# Power spectrual density of white Gaussian noise

Tags: power-spectral-density

I know that power spectral density of white Gaussian noise is
$\frac{N_0}{2}$.

In a simulation I want to plot a system output and its very important to define the value of $N_0$,I want to know what is $N_0$ and its value?

Comment: Um, your question shows your problem: "it's important to **define** $N_0$". Exactly. $N_0$ is the noise density, and you *define* it for your simulation. As simulations simulate a real system, you must describe the noise that this system sees, so that you can derive the noise density.

Comment: Thanks dear Marcus , for a theoretical analyze how can define the N0? does it have any formula to assume for a simple calculation? (for example for ideal system ( for a white noise input signal and a narrow band pass filter) what can PSD be?

Comment: For a simulation, **you** must describe your system. Noise density is one of the crucial aspects of that description. It can take any non-negative value.

Comment: That being said, you can always assume a baseline Noise density based on *Johnson-Nyquist* Noise, which would have a power density of $k_b T$. Add in estimates for the temperature of your system, and also don't forget that all active components have a positive *Noise Figure*. It's totally unclear what the values of these Noise Figures are, and estimating them is the central problem that only you, with knowledge of your system, can do.

Answer (score 0):

$N_0$ is one of the characteristics of your system, you don't have to define it yourself but to know which is the one of the system you are using. A differente case would be if what you wanted was to see any kind of behaviour related to the $N_0$. In that case, you should just make a sweep in the value of this variable. As Marcus said, you can have a first aproach of the noise in your system using the Thermal noise.